# How do I convert the logback.xml configuration file to an application.yml configuration file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, yaml, logback

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
<pattern>%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-3level %logger{5} - %msg %n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
<logger name="jdbc" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="jdbc.sqltiming" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="jdbc.audit" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="jdbc.resultset" level="OFF"/>
<logger name="jdbc.resultsettable" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="jdbc.connection" level="OFF"/>
<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
</configuration>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wQcM.png)

I am trying to disable logs such as jdbc.audit in the application.yml file, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am writing to you from South Korea. I am using Google's Gemini translation service to communicate with you, so please bear with me if there are any misunderstandings or errors in my English.

```
  datasource:
      url: jdbc:log4jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
      username: TODAY
      password: Oracle12345678
      driver-class-name: net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.DriverSpy
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    org:
      springframework:
        jdbc:
          level: off
          core: off
          audit: off
```

I am facing an issue with log configuration in my application. When I use the logback.xml file to configure logging, specific logs like jdbc.audit are successfully suppressed. However, when I try to achieve the same configuration using the application.yml file, the log levels defined in the file seem to have no effect, and the jdbc.audit logs are still being generated.

Comment: You are configuring `org.springframework.jdbc.audit` not `jdbc.audit` as in your xml configuration. Remove the `org.springframework` part in your config.